# Remove array count in Typescript

Tags: arrays, console.log

I have an array like `containerAccessories: (2) [5, 10]` . If I print this array it will display count also, but I don't need this.

**Actual Result**

```
console.log(this.containerAccessories)   // result will be (2) [5, 10]
```

**Expected Result**

```
console.log(this.containerAccessories) // [5, 10]
```

Comment: You want to change `console.log` behavior? That's browser specific; Chrome will show that, Firefox won't.

Comment: Where do you check the console output? Is it in Chrome or Firefox developer tools? They just format the way they like it. So, actually, it is just an information about the count but the real content is just the Array [5, 10]. What is your goal here? Are you going to use the value somewhere and are afraid that the count could somehow be a problem?

Comment: If you want to print out this format as a string, you can use join. `console.log('[${this.containerAccessories.join(', ')}]');` (Replace the outer single quotes with back-ticks)

Comment: I am checking in chrome. So I doubt, it will affect the back end coding. Now I clear. Thank you